Confusion about the form of Cauchy–Riemann equations in fluid dynamics
The Cauchy–Riemann equations are
$${\displaystyle {\begin{aligned}{\frac {\partial u }{\partial x}}&={\frac {\partial v }{\partial y}}\,,&{\frac {\partial u }{\partial y}}&=-{\frac {\partial v }{\partial x}}\,.\end{aligned}}}$$
for a complex function $f=u+iv$.
In fluid dynamics we also have the CR equations of the form
$${\displaystyle {\begin{aligned}u&={\frac {\partial \varphi }{\partial x}}={\frac {\partial \psi }{\partial y}},&v&={\frac {\partial \varphi }{\partial y}}=-{\frac {\partial \psi }{\partial x}}\,.\end{aligned}}}$$
where $\mathbf v=(u,v)$ is a vector velocity field.
I want to derive them from the equation of a streamline
$${\displaystyle {dx \over u}={dy \over v}}$$
from there I have 2 options:
$$ udy-vdx=0\tag1$$
$$ vdx-udy=0\tag2$$
they only differ by a multiple of $-1$.
So I can define a vector potential $\psi$ to be either
$$d\psi_1=udy-vdx\tag1$$
or
$$d\psi_2=vdx-udy\tag2$$
(for steady state $\psi$ is constant so $d\psi=0$.)
Now, if I write the differential 1-form of $\psi$
$$d\psi = \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial x} \, dx + \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial y} \, dy$$
and I equate the partial derivatives with the velocity components I get:
For the first equation $(1)$:
$${\displaystyle {\begin{aligned}u&={\frac {\partial \varphi }{\partial x}}={\frac {\partial \psi }{\partial y}},&v&={\frac {\partial \varphi }{\partial y}}=-{\frac {\partial \psi }{\partial x}}\,.\end{aligned}}}$$
and for the second choice $(2)$:
$${\displaystyle {\begin{aligned}u&={\frac {\partial \varphi }{\partial x}}=-{\frac {\partial \psi }{\partial y}},&v&={\frac {\partial \varphi }{\partial y}}={\frac {\partial \psi }{\partial x}}\,.\end{aligned}}}$$
I get the Cauchy–Riemann equations but with the minus sign in the first equation rather than in the second if I choose the equation $(2)$, but how can that be?
I get the wrong form of the CR equations just by choosing an equivalent but other form of an equation?
Is the second form of the CR equations valid? I think not, they are defined in the first way, so I am confused how do I get a crucially different result from a trivial choice?
